# How to generate a random number/String based on a pattern in java?

Tags: java, parsing, random, pattern-matching

I want to generate a random number based on a pattern like:

```
random.int= pattern="[0-9]{%len%}"   
random.big_integer= pattern="[0-9]{%len%}"  
random.long= pattern="[0-9]{%len%}"   
random.string= pattern="[A-Z][a-z]{0,%len%}"  
random.char= pattern="[A-Z]{1}"  
random.byte= pattern="[A-Z][0-9]{1}"  
random.short= pattern="[0-9]{%len%}"  
random.float= pattern="[0-9]{%len%}\\.[0-9]{%scl%}"  
random.double= pattern="[0-9]{%len%}\\.[0-9]{%scl%}"  
random.big_decimal= pattern="[0-9]{%len%}\\.[0-9]{%scl%}"
```

So, my inputs will be "len","scl" and the datatype. And based on these inputs,
I will have to read the corresponding pattern and generate the output. This output should 
be random for every call during a single run. Output should be same if I rerun the program.

What is the best approach I can take to achieve this in JAVA ?

For example, if I call generateRandomOutput("float",5,2) [datatype,length,scale] my output 
should have a random float number like for example: 21453.67 (This is based on the pattern "random.float" described above)

Comment: Step 1. Post code that shows your efforts so far. The question with no code to back it is not clear enough.

Comment: Hi Marko, I am working on the best approach to this problem, like what kind of library can I use to achieve this. so, haven't started on the code yet...

Comment: Nothing in your questions sounds like it will need a library, all the ingredients are in the JDK. But I don't understand your problem fully.

Comment: Basically i need to generate a random String/number based on the datatype,length and scale passed... I am having the patterns customizable because I can add custom datatypes...

Comment: Giving a concrete example of input and output would go a long way.

Comment: For example, if I call generateRandomOutput("float",5,2) [datatype,length,scale] my output should have a random float number like for example: 21453.67 (This is based on the pattern "random.float" described above)

Comment: If you do not share a single line of code... what do you expect... ? You generate random numbers with Math.random() and then interpret them as you wish...

Answer (score 1):

Putting it simply, it is a change of base. You can generate a random char by getting a `Math.random` and multiplying by 26, the result tells you the position of the random letter in your alphabet(`[A-Z]`).

Getting a String with two random characters needs you multiplying by 26^2 and changing the number to base 26(or alternatively, getting a random number multiplied by 26 two times).

Comment: Hmm but how do I generate it based on the pattern?

Comment: `if (pattern.equals("char")) then ....`. If you use Java 7 I believe you can use switch with strings, too :-D.

Comment: but i need a generic parsing technique which can decode any pattern ...

Comment: Then ** PROGRAM IT ** We are not here to do your job. I helped with some pointers in case you do not need where to start the program that ** YOU ** need. If you have a specific issue you will get a specific answer. If you have a vague, generic question you will get a vague, generic answer. If you just want the code, don't bother asking here.

Comment: i was just asking for an idea or an approach to start with.. like is there any readymade API availabe to do this ? Anyways thanks for your help ..

Answer (score 1):

Try out [QuickCheck](http://java.net/projects/quickcheck/pages/Home)

It provides great [primitive generators](http://quickcheck.java.net/nonav/javadoc/index.html) for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a random number generator that you can "seed", so you can supply the same seed each run so that runs are reproducible.  You can seed java.util.Random.

Next, I'd suggest you write a standard routine that, given a length and an alphabet, will supply a string of that many random characters.  Then write routines for each of your data types to call the common routine to get the character strings, and convert them into the desired type.

The standard routine is fairly simple:

- Receive length and alphabet parms.
- Get the next random integer from your RNG.
- Take the random integer and calculate the modulus of the length of the alphabet.
- Use the modulus to select the next character from your alphabet -- shove that into the result string.
- Repeat until you've accumulated the specified number of characters.

In the type-specific routines you call the above common function with the proper parms (twice, with inserted ".", for float/double/big decimal), then use Datatype.getDatatype (substituting the appropriate data type name) to convert the resulting string to the proper type.  The type-specific routines are thus mostly "boilerplate".

The "alphabet" passed to the common routine is "0123456789" the numeric types, "ABCD..WXYZ" for your "char" type, "ABCD..WXYZ0123..789" for your "byte" type (or did you intend for it to be "0123456789ABCDEF"?).

Comment: Actually I came across this API and looks to do exactly what I need ... http://code.google.com/p/xeger/

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to determine all the possible strings which conform to a regular expression, only some simple regular expression such as you have. As such I doubt there is a library which will help you.

I suggest you use a simpler format of your own such as `A` => A-Z, `a` => a-z, `d` => 0-9, nnn as repeat and any other character as itself.

e.f. instead of

```
random.byte= pattern="[A-Z][0-9]{1}"
```

I would have

```
random.byte.pattern=Ad
```

which would be much simpler to parse.

Answer (score 0):

> Output should be same if I rerun the program.

Doesn't sound like you actually want it to be *random*?

Look at one way hashing functions like MD5, SHA, etc.